# iOS UIImageview image resets to default image on 1st orientation change, why is that?

Tags: ios, xcode, mobile, autolayout

I'm using UIimagePicker to select image and display it to UIImageview, however something weird is going on. If i use the image picker and select a photo and add it to the image view and change orientation of the iphone the imageview image resets to the default image. but if i select the image again using UIimagePicker everything works fine the image stays.So this happens only the first time orientation changes while the view is loaded. Any thoughts?

Comment: Does your `UIImage` have a specific value for the `imageOrientation` property? I'm not really sure how a `UIImageView` behaves when it needs a different orientation than the image has.

Comment: I havn't set a orientation property. This happens only 1st time when i'm in that view controller